# Memory address from pointer

Tags: c#, memory, ram, memory-address

Yesterday i started messing with c# and VAMemory.ddl. My goal is to make a Program that will Read the player's HP from a game "League of Legends".
I found out the static address of the HP and read it:

```
vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)address);
```

It worked pretty well, and i could see my in-game HP from my program, but since it is a static address and it changes every time i restart the game, i have to find the address every time.
So i started to look for pointers. I followed a couple of tutorials and after about a Hour i could see my HP in cheatengine, restart the game and without chaneging the address still see it.

But i don't understand how would i implement it to my program, i couldn't find any tutorials. :/

Here is what i found from Cheatengine:

[image: CE]

Current HP - League of Legends.exe - 0x032871FC - 0x58, 0x6C0, 0x42C, 0x90, 0x448 - float

Comment: You need to be very careful with what you do to memory in various games as many of them have anti-cheat systems that catch when you tamper with their memory.

Comment: "I don't understand how to program" and "I need a tutorial" are not questions; this is a question and answer site. Do you have a *specific* question?

Comment: Yes, my question is How can i read a float from memory, if i have the Pointer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach to solve your problem. Note that the software need to be a 32 bit software!

Step one is to get the base address of the process:

```
Process GameProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("GameProcessName").FirstOrDefault();
IntPtr BaseAddress = GameProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress;
```

Based on this address you are able to step through the pointers like (exemplary offset of 0x58)

```
int ReadBytes;
IntPtr BasePlusOneAddress = IntPtr.Add(BaseAddress, 0x58);
IntPtr BasePlusOneValue = (IntPtr)BitConverter.ToInt32(MemoryHandler.ReadMemory(GameProcess, BasePlusOneAddress, 4, out ReadBytes), 0);
```

You can use the value now as pointer again.

This leads to a simple function like

```
void IntPtr GetOffsetPointer(Process P, IntPtr BasePointer, Int32 Offset)
{
    int ReadBytes;
    IntPtr OffsetAddress = IntPtr.Add(BasePointer, Offset);
    return (IntPtr)BitConverter.ToInt32(MemoryHandler.ReadMemory(P, OffsetAddress, 4, out ReadBytes), 0);
}
```

**EDIT:** The `MemoryHandler` just wraps the [ReadProcessMemory function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) of windows. This is just an example - so you have to implement your own functionality. A greate example is available at [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/670373/csharp-read-write-another-process-memory).

Comment: Where did you get the "MemoryHandler" from? Error: The name 'MemoryHandler' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Hmm, When doing :                                                                                IntPtr BasePlusOneAddress = IntPtr.Add(BaseAddress, 0x58); vam.ReadFloat((IntPtr)BasePlusOneAddress);                                                            i get 2,959361E+21

Comment: what type is vam of and what value should be at the position?

Comment: I used your function to get the "BasePlusOneAddress" and it was 13303896, converted it to hex CB0058 and used it in cheatengine but still got the weird number [Cheatengine](https://i.gyazo.com/30397b84de45d1faf7c98afd124f961a.png)